# Very Strange Repeated TCP/IP/DNS Warnings

Tags: dns, tunnel

Every 75 minutes a warning is posted in my system event log.  With very few exceptions, this continues 24/7 and has occurred for months.  The warning is from source DNS Client Events, event ID 1014, description:

> "Name resolution for the name tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org timed out
>   after none of the configured DNS servers responded."

There are one or two other URLs that sometimes appear in place of tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org.

For 10 minutes after the posting of this warning, no new internet connections succeed.  I.E., if the IE browser is launched, the circulating arrow appears with the "Waiting for ..." message and this will continue for 10 minutes.  After that time, the home page will appear and for the next 65 minutes all is OK.

I removed power from my Cisco DPC3825 residential gateway for a few minutes to see if the times of the warnings would shift (possibly indicating that the problem is in the gateway itself), but the times did not shift.  Subsequent warnings continued to be posted on the same, original schedule.

Does anyone have any suggestions, either as to the cause, or for anything I can do to obtain more diagnostic information?  It might be helpful if there were a way to monitor ***ALL*** TCP/IP/DNS activity immediately preceding the posting of the DNS warning.  Because the timing of the warnings is so uniform, I can predict within seconds when the next one will occur.

I am running under Windows 7 on a Dell T1700.

(Sorry if this duplicates a question I submitted yesterday as a guest, but I was unable to relocate that question or any answers to it.)

Comment: This is telling you that the DNS servers you have configured became unavailable.  If you haven't explicitly set these, then you are most likely using your router for DNS, which in turn is using the ones provided by your ISP.  I would eliminate this as a possibility by changing the DNS in your router to use google `8.8.8.8` `8.8.4.4`.  If this fixes it, then open a ticket with your ISP to find out why their servers become unavailable.

Comment: I can't answer the question entirely. But at least I can tell you `tunnel.cfw.trustedsource.org` is related to **McAfee** security software you're probably running. It's quite possible the issues you're experiencing are McAfee's fault. Especially if all your internet requests are going through them first (i.e. you're configured to use *their* DNS servers which seems to be the case).

Comment: See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.